# Android App crashing only on specific Tablets - XmlPullParserException

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, multi-window, android-xmlpullparser

I have an app published on Google Play. For two months, some crashes appear on my Google Play Console. The log is pasted below. Note that this crash so far only appeared for owners of those devices: Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 and Asus ZenPad 10, all on Android 5.

I already ran a Google Search about crashes on Tablets when enabling multiwindow (because there is something like that written in the log), but I did not find any satisfactory result so far. In my tablet emulator, I was not able to reproduce this.

Do you have an idea what could cause the issue? If I should post a specific file, let me know. I did not insert them for a start, because as the app runs perfectly fine on must devices, so I don't think that this is an obviuos coding related issue. Thanks in advance!
Stacktrace (full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/ds3A2W06)):

```
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:3783)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3651)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1865)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1831)
      at myname.TestFragment.access$000 (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.onAttach (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.onCreateView (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.updateHeaderCheckBox (TestFragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onActivityCreated (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreateAnimator (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onMultiWindowModeChanged (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onOptionsItemSelected (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setNextAnim (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addRetainedFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.animateRemoveFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.beginTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchConfigurationChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMultiWindowModeChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dump (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentById (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentByTag (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeFadeAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeOpenCloseAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.postponePostponableTransactions (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setMaxLifecycle (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.throwException (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addRetainedFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.animateRemoveFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.beginTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchConfigurationChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMultiWindowModeChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dump (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    ...(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMultiWindowModeChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dump (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentById (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentByTag (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeFadeAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeOpenCloseAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.postponePostponableTransactions (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
   ...(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.transitToStyleIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.detach (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.interactsWith (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.isFragmentPostponed (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.trackAddedFragmentsInPop (BackStackRecord.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.destroyItem (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.isViewFromObject (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.makeFragmentName (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.restoreState (FragmentPagerAdapter.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.isDecorView (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.pageLeft (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.requestParentDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.dispatchOnScrollStateChanged (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java)
      at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:18648)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5832)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.addPreDrawListener (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.clamp (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.constrainChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.dispatchDependentViewsChanged (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDescendantRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDesiredAnchoredChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDesiredAnchoredChildRectWithoutConstraints (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getTopSortedChildren (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.isPointInChildBounds (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChildWithAnchor (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildByInset (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onChildViewsChanged (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedPreScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onStopNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.releaseTempRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.resetTouchBehaviors (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.setWindowInsets (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.findFirstDependency (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.getOverlapPixelsForOffset (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:18648)
      ...
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6134)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1399)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1194)
    Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 
      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray (BitmapDrawable.java:761)
      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate (BitmapDrawable.java:726)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:1155)
      at android.graphics.drawable.RotateDrawable.inflate (RotateDrawable.java:453)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:1155)
      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:1068)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie (Resources.java:3767)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3651)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1865)
      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1831)
      at myname.TestFragment.access$000 (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.onAttach (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.onCreateView (TestFragment.java)
      at myname.TestFragment.updateHeaderCheckBox (TestFragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onActivityCreated (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreateAnimator (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onMultiWindowModeChanged (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onOptionsItemSelected (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setNextAnim (Fragment.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addRetainedFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.animateRemoveFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.beginTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchConfigurationChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMultiWindowModeChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dump (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentById (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentByTag (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeFadeAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeOpenCloseAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.postponePostponableTransactions (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setMaxLifecycle (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.throwException (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addRetainedFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.animateRemoveFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.beginTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchConfigurationChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMultiWindowModeChanged (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentActivityCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentAttached (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOnFragmentViewCreated (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsMenuClosed (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dump (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePostponedTransaction (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentById (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentByTag (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeFadeAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeOpenCloseAnimation (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.postponePostponableTransactions (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setBackStackIndex (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setMaxLifecycle (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.throwException (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
      at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java)
      ...
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:18648)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5832)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.addPreDrawListener (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.clamp (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.constrainChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.dispatchDependentViewsChanged (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDescendantRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDesiredAnchoredChildRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getDesiredAnchoredChildRectWithoutConstraints (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.getTopSortedChildren (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.isPointInChildBounds (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChildWithAnchor (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.offsetChildByInset (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onChildViewsChanged (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedPreScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onStopNestedScroll (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.performIntercept (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.releaseTempRect (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.resetTouchBehaviors (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.setWindowInsets (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.findFirstDependency (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.getOverlapPixelsForOffset (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java)
      at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java)
      at android.view.View.measure (View.java:18648)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:5832)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:430)

      ...
```

Note that I replaced my original package name with "myname" in this trace.

Comment: it tells resource not found exception, are you sure any res items was not relocated during updates or any other ways

Comment: I don't think so. On all other devices it works, also on my tablet emulator. I also don't use a tablet-specific layout. It did not move around any resources in the last time. Also, would it even build if there was an invalid resource reference?